# get all posts ID from a category

Tags: wordpress

I need to get ID's of posts from a given category in the right side bar.

I am doing this to get post contents in a page if the page name and post title matches

```
$slug = basename(get_permalink());
query_posts("category_name={$slug}");
```

This works great. But on the right side bar I am getting 5 recent posts. I would like to hack that to show all the posts from the category which is displaying in the page. Eventually i would like to use the links as anchors to the post on the page

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd use get_posts or a new WP_Query but I'll give you the answer that works with your method.

You're getting the number of posts that you've set as the default per page. You need to override that value. -1 = all.

```
query_posts( array( 
    'category_name'  => $slug,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
) );
```